# How can I stop repeating cells in a table view?

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview

I have a problem in which whenever my tableView reloads, the same cells repeat.

Is there something that can stop this? I tried to search but unfortunately no luck finding a solution, so I decided to post here. I'm new so if I miss anything please let me know.

This is my code:

```
var list:[String] = []

class Services: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    var videos: [String] = []

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]

        return(cell)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return list.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 172
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let secondVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "ChangeTitle") as! Services
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

//        print(scoreLabelA.text!)

        arrayOfCellData = [cellData(cell: 1, text: "Meow")]

        tableView?.reloadData()

        handle = ref.child("ServiceA").observe(.childAdded, with: { DataSnapshot in
            if let item = DataSnapshot.value as? String {
                list.append(item)
                self.tableView?.reloadData()
            }
        })

        tableView.backgroundColor = .clear

        tableView?.delegate = self
        tableView?.dataSource = self
    }
}
```

Is there any way to fix it? Many thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because `var list:[String] = []` is outside your `Services` class it is being persisted.
Either move the property inside the class or empty it before you repopulate by doing:

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    arrayOfCellData = [cellData(cell: 1, text: "Meow")]

    tableView?.reloadData()

//Add this:
list = []

    handle = ref.child("ServiceA").observe(.childAdded, with: { DataSnapshot in
        if let item = DataSnapshot.value as? String {
            list.append(item)
            self.tableView?.reloadData()
        }
    })
```